# Deploying a Rails site giving a cryptic error I can't find out what it means

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, refinerycms, rvm-capistrano

This site has been up and running for quite some time. I don't think anything has been changed in terms of gems and such. I am running cap deploy and receive this cryptic error below. The release name "20140407162521" that is complaining about doesn't even exist on the server either. Does anyone know what this is related to?

```
*** [err :: dev.example.com] stdin: is not a tty
*** [err :: dev.example.com] rake aborted!
*** [err :: dev.example.com] Invalid argument - /home/jeffc/public_html/dev/statusexpo_proj/releases/20140407162521/tmp/cache/assets/D48/850/.permissions_check.16572040.6927.224951
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:30:in `initialize'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:30:in `open'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:30:in `rescue in atomic_write'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/file/atomic.rb:24:in `atomic_write'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:92:in `write_entry'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:140:in `write_entry'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/cache.rb:364:in `block in write'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/cache.rb:520:in `instrument'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/cache.rb:362:in `write'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:90:in `cache_set'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:53:in `cache_set_hash'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:29:in `cache_asset'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] /home/jeffc/www/dev/statusexpo_proj/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: dev.example.com] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and delete tmp contents manually rm -rf tmp/, then deploy again to see if that helps?

May be related to: [assets:precompile fails with "File exists" on Rails 3.2.15 with Asset Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815655/assetsprecompile-fails-with-file-exists-on-rails-3-2-15-with-asset-pipeline)